# How do I send a push notification from SQL Server to C# code?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a Stored Procedure that runs periodically (from a Database Trigger), and it returns a string. I want to send that string (whenever that SP runs) to my C# Code.

How do I do that in SQL Server?  I'd rather not simply have the C# code poll a table in the database since I don't know how that will perform.

Comment: Why not have the C# Code just execute the STored Procedure directly?

Comment: Because the SP is executed under some conditions, triggers, etc so it has to be executed from the server itself not the C# code.

Comment: Exactly, notified with the returned string from that SP

Comment: That's a different question than the one you asked; you don't need an agent job. One possible way to solve it would be to have the SP output to a table; and then have your C# code periodically check that table for data. (Possibly a timestamp + whatever string).

Comment: Well that's the problem, I want to save performance because like that I will have to add too many loops to the C# code. So it's not possible to do that?

Comment: Have you profiled it? SQL Server lacks a 'push' notification process; so in some way, shape, or form, someone is going to have to periodically check that table for new data. You could potentially add code for the SP to kick off the Agent job, and the Agent job use curl to send a POST to your server; but you'll need an API endpoint up to receive that post; and it reduces security on your SQL Server, since you're literally asking it to send data across the 'net. The Agent job would have to enable xp_cmdshell; which would also reduce security. Yea; your safest course is polling.

Comment: Oh if that's the only way then polling is faster. I guess

Comment: There is another option, but only if the client and server are on the same machine - you can enlist for notifications from the SQL server http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/144344/Query-Notification-using-SqlDependency-and-SqlCach
However, polling is not necessarily a bad thing. Just make sure you're doing it in a reasonable place, and ideally using asynchronous code with no shared state.

Comment: @Luaan yes they're on the same machine.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way to do this is to write a SQLCLR procedure that sends a message to your C# code.

How is your C# code executing? Is it in IIS? If not can you make it start a web server and accept a SOAP or REST call?

SOAP calls are a little annoying on SQLCLR, but doable if your well invested in WCF. The path of least resistance is to make a REST call, or even just send the string via a POST body with content-type of text/plain. If you give me more details as to your setup and what your comfortable with on the C# side, I can give you more specific guidance.